# Ignoring case with __startswith

Tags: django

I'm trying to filter an object based off its first letter with:

```
topics = SpecialtyCategory.objects.filter(name__startswith=request.GET.get('filter'))
```

The problem is that the name could be "Example" or "example" and I want to get all SpecialtyCategory regardless of the case.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You want [`__istartswith`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#istartswith):

```
topics = SpecialtyCategory.objects.filter(name__istartswith=request.GET.get('filter'))
```

There is a whole complement of `i` versions of queryset filters, which are all case insensitive: icontains, iexact, iregex, etc.